# Showing user control in panel

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, user-controls

I am trying to use UserControl in panel of windows form. But it is not being showed.

Method of the form:

```
public void SetContent(UserControl control) {
        contentPanel.Controls.Clear();
        control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        contentPanel.Controls.Add(control);
        control.Show();
        contentPanel.Show();
        control.Refresh();
        contentPanel.Refresh();
        Refresh();
}
```

Initialization

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();  
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    MyForm form;
    Application.Run(form=new MyForm());
    form.SetContent(new MyControl());
}
```

Comment: You could set a BackColor in the uo to make it show better. The code looks ok, but all lines after the Add are not really needed, unless the controls were invisible..

Comment: Yes, those lines are useless, the user control is invinsible anyway.

Comment: No code after `Application.Run(form=new MyForm());` will run. Best not even change anything in the `programm.cs` file, unless you really need to.

Comment: Actually, I had called SetContent after Application.Run and this method was executed only after closing form. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use UserControl in panel of windows form, you can refer to the following code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myControl = new UserControl1();
        contentPanel.Controls.Add(myControl);
    }
```

[image]